# How to configure an existing cognito user pool to amplify Angular app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to build an Angular app which authorize users through Norwegian Bank ID. To connect that service i will be using AWS Cognito. When i add an Auth from the Amplify CLI it automatically add a attribute called email.
But the Bank ID authorization response doesn't include field email in the payload. So i keep getting errors. Is there way to configure an existing identity pool / user pool while using the CLI?

i tried editing the parameters.json file in Auth folder in Amplify but while pushing i keep getting an error like this.

```
Event Type: create
Reason: 1 validation error detected: Value '[name]' at 'autoVerifiedAttributes' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must satisfy enum value set: [phone_number, email]] (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 4d0bbb64-4754-11e9-b31e-4da234436449)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cognito User pool, In the section "Which standard attributes are required?" these attributes, [phone_number, email] is set as "Required". These attributes were selected when the pool was created and cannot be changed.

Your Question
 Is there way to configure an existing identity pool / user pool while using the CLI?
Answer
yes, Please create a Cognito user Pool and Cognito Identity Pool as required.

Add the configurations manually to AWS Amplify (aws-exports.js)

Then fire the CLI commands.

Robin

Comment: The aws file reads textually : "// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten." why should you edit it manually then?

Comment: While installing AWS Amplify it will ask whether Cognito User pool needs to be created or it should use an existing one. If already you have an existing Cognito user pool, select that option and proceed.